# how can i create a free public github Account for life time is this possible

Tags: git, github

Here I have a couple of Web Application on node.js which I intended to share and store. Before I have a free account for 1 month in GitHub with in that I shared some of my Applications code and now the free tire has expired and i cannot publish my code further. As I'm a student i cannot afford to get a premium membership. So can one update me on how to use GitHub for life time for free (or) with some other alternatives to GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you can see in this [link](https://github.com/pricing) there is actually a life-time free plan avialable you.